# Different types of SVG not showing

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to use an svg in order to do a pattern in my background for a new website I'm developing. The thing is I found one that I like it and im trying to customize to use it.

I downloaded the SVG that looks like this

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="199" viewBox="0 0 100 199"><g fill="#000"><path d="M0 199V0h1v1.99L100 199h-1.12L1 4.22V199H0zM100 2h-.12l-1-2H100v2z"></path></g></svg>
```

If I do something like

```
.my-div {
   background-image: url("mysvg-black.svg")
}
```

it works perfect but it's black, and I don't want it black so I open up my photoshop and change the color from it.

I changed the color to red (for example) then I exported as SVG and got this

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="417" height="829" viewBox="0 0 417 829">
  <image width="417" height="829" xlink:href="data:img/png;base64,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"/>
</svg>
```

But when now i do

```
.my-div {
   background-image: url("mysvg-red.svg")
}
```

Nothing shows up

Can anyone help my with this?

I found that the exported from photoshop has a lot of tags that the downloaded doesn't

Thank you!

Comment: why its `xlink:href="data:img....` and not just `href="data:img....`?

Comment: No need of photoshop to turn it red :

`<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="199" viewBox="0 0 100 199">
  <g fill="red">
    <path d="M0 199V0h1v1.99L100 199h-1.12L1 4.22V199H0zM100 2h-.12l-1-2H100v2z"></path>
  </g>
</svg>` update the value of fill to red.  see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/fill & https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/fill/

Comment: you can embed the SVG inside the background without using it as external file and then it's would be easy to adjust

Comment: I think photoshop is the problem, don't know why it's exporting them badly. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your SVG code is very basic. If you want change only color, Just change the fill attribute value of the g tag. Like this;

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="199" viewBox="0 0 100 199">
    <g fill="#f00">
        <path d="M0 199V0h1v1.99L100 199h-1.12L1 4.22V199H0zM100 2h-.12l-1-2H100v2z"></path>
    </g>
</svg>
```

*You can change the measure with `background-size`. The SVG you just created was big in size.*

For more complex operations, you will need software that you can manipulate SVG.